# How do I find start and end indices in python list for all the rows

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, loops

My code -

```
df=pd.read_csv("file")
l1=[]
l2=[]
for i in range(0,len(df['unions']),len(df['district'])):
    l1.append(' '.join((df['unions'][i], df['district'][i])))
    l2.append(({"entities": [[(ele.start(), ele.end() - 1) for ele in re.finditer(r'\S+', df['unions'][i])] ,df['subdistrict'][i]],}))

TRAIN_DATA=list(zip(l1,l2))
print(TRAIN_DATA)
```

Result - `[('Dhansagar Bagerhat', {'entities': [[(0, 8)], 'Sarankhola']})]`

My expected output - `[('Dhansagar Bagerhat', {'entities': [[(0, 8)], 'Sarankhola'],[[(10, 17)], 'AnyLabel']})]`
How do I get this output for all the rows? I am getting the result for only one row. It seems like my loop is not working. Can anyone please point out my mistake?

My csv file looks like this. "AnyLabel" is another column. I have around 500 rows -

```
unions        subdistrict   district 
Dhansagar     Sarankhola    Bagerhat 
Daibagnyahati Morrelganj    Bagerhat 
Ramchandrapur Morrelganj    Bagerhat 
Kodalia       Mollahat      Bagerhat
```

Comment: Show us the original dataframe.

Comment: Could you please copy and paste it as text?

Comment: Yes I have added the text format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `str.join`:

```
df=pd.read_csv("file")
l1=[]
l2=[]

for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    l1.append(' '.join((row['unions'], row['district'])))
    l2.append(({"entities": [[[ele.start(), ele.end() - 1], ele.group(0)] for ele in re.finditer(r'\S+', ' '.join([row['unions'] ,row['subdistrict']]))]}))
    

TRAIN_DATA=list(zip(l1,l2))
print(TRAIN_DATA)
```

Output:

```
[('Dhansagar Bagerhat', {'entities': [[[0, 8], 'Dhansagar'], [[10, 19], 'Sarankhola']]}), ('Daibagnyahati Bagerhat', {'entities': [[[0, 12], 'Daibagnyahati'], [[14, 23], 'Morrelganj']]}), ('Ramchandrapur Bagerhat', {'entities': [[[0, 12], 'Ramchandrapur'], [[14, 23], 'Morrelganj']]}), ('Kodalia Bagerhat', {'entities': [[[0, 6], 'Kodalia'], [[8, 15], 'Mollahat']]})]
```

Comment: Getting the same error here. l1.append(' '.join((row['unions'], row['district'])))
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Actually I am getting the same error again. l1.append(' '.join((row['unions'], row['district'])))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found

Comment: Also, can you please look into my expected output? I wanted to have indices for both words

Comment: It worked for another csv file. It was an issue with union column. Thank you

Comment: But my expected output is different

Answer (score 1):

You're using `range` wrong, you're basically telling it to iterate all the numbers from 0 to `len(df['unions'])` but to do it in steps of `len(df['district'])` which is the same length. So you're basically telling it to iterate across only the first row. You can see that by printing out the row numbers:

```
for i in range(0,len(df['unions']),len(df['district'])):
    print(i)
```

Also, you're not supposed to iterate over rows like that anyway, use instead `df.iterrows()`

```
df=pd.read_csv("file")
l1=[]
l2=[]

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    l1.append(' '.join((row['unions'], row['district'])))
    l2.append(({"entities": [[(ele.start(), ele.end() - 1) for ele in re.finditer(r'\S+', ' '.join([row['unions'] ,row['subdistrict']]))]]}))
```

Comment: @U12-Forward can you point out where please? I'll fix it

Comment: The curly brace.

Comment: But I am getting this error l1.append(' '.join((row['unions'], row['district'])))
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: @bellatrix sorry i forgot `i`, try again with edited version

Comment: But it's getting it as float.  l1.append(' '.join((row['unions'], row['district'])))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found

Comment: Also, please look into my expected output.  I couldn't print the start & end indices for the 2nd word.